# ggplot does not process theme_bw()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a histogram of brain activation across two different conditions, and I have the main plot working. However, I would like to change the orientation of the labels of the x-axis, as well as the legend labels and the font.. All of these pass through the theme() argument, but for some reason, my plot does not seem to take them in to account.

```
     x = colnames(data[,c(3:8,12:21)])
     y1 = meand3h
     y2 = meand5h

     to_plot <- data.frame(x=x,y1=y1,y2=y2) 
     melted<-melt(to_plot, id="x")


     p<-ggplot(melted,aes(x=x,y=value,fill=variable))

     p
     + scale_shape_discrete(name="Group",labels=c("Three days","Five days")) 
     + geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=1) 
     + labs(y = "Level of Activation")
     + labs(title = "Activation of Brain Areas After Training")    
     + theme_bw(base_size = 12, base_family = "Times") 
     + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(angle=180))
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Outside of functions and expressions inside `{}` you need to place the line breaks after the `+`.

Comment: Seems to work fine: `windowsFonts()$serif; ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + geom_point() + theme_bw(base_size = 32, base_family = "serif") + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(angle=180))`.

Comment: Please supply `data` as a minimal working example.

Answer (score -2):

It is because you have two themes that are causing contrast, choose between theme() and theme_bw().